# CMake Fortran Dependency Checking

Tags: dependencies, cmake, fortran

According to the "Mastering CMake" book 4th edition, the "output_required_files" command should take a source file and produce a list of all other source file it depends on. So far I tried it with Fortran source files and it didn't work, it basically creates an empty file which supposedly should contain a list of source file dependencies. I am trying this on Linux.

I found this post online as well which covers the same issue and apparently no solution from anyone:

http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2009-September/031904.html

Does the command actually work or it's something that the author's of the book are still planning to implement?

I would appreciate it if Bill Hoffman or Ken Martin can comment on this and perhaps give us a working example of how to get this working.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You should ask this on the CMake mailing list, your chances of getting an answer is much higher there.

Answer (score -2):

Got the answer from the mailing list:

http://www.vtk.org/Bug/view.php?id=12214

Comment: You should consider explaining how you solved your problem in your answer. After doing so, you should consider accepting your answer.